# website using nuxt and @nuxtjs/pwa not caching google fonts

Tags: service-worker, nuxt.js

I created my app with `npx create-nuxt-app`, then added `npm install @nuxtjs/pwa --save`. I'm including a google font in index.html with:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" data-n-head="true">
```

I tested my app in offline mode in Chrome by clicking the "Offline" checkbox in the devtools/application tab, and reloading. Everything is cached except for the font.

I then added:

```
workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*',
            handler: 'cacheFirst',
            method: 'GET'
        },
    ]
}
```

to the `nuxt.config.js` file but I can't get the font to be cached. I've tried a number of variations on the urlPattern.

Nuxt is generating a service worker for me, and it looks like this:

```
importScripts('/_nuxt/workbox.3de3418b.js')

const workboxSW = new self.WorkboxSW({
  "cacheId": "my-app",
  "clientsClaim": true,
  "directoryIndex": "/"
})

workboxSW.precache([
  {
    "url": "/_nuxt/app.bb74329360a7ee70c2af.js",
    "revision": "8477c51cbf9d3188f34f1d61ec1ae6bc"
  },
  {
    "url": "/_nuxt/layouts/default.ce9446c7c3fffa50cfd2.js",
    "revision": "504d33b2d46614e60d919e01ec59bbc8"
  },
  {
    "url": "/_nuxt/manifest.912c22076a54259e047d.js",
    "revision": "a51a74b56987961c8d34afdcf4efa85c"
  },
  {
    "url": "/_nuxt/pages/index.6bfd6741c6dfd79fd94d.js",
    "revision": "1a80379a5d35d5d4084d4c2b85e1ee10"
  },
  {
    "url": "/_nuxt/vendor.f681eb653617896fcd64.js",
    "revision": "59c58901fd5142fdaac57cbee8c1aeb4"
  }
])


workboxSW.router.registerRoute(new RegExp('/_nuxt/.*'), workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET')

workboxSW.router.registerRoute(new RegExp('/.*'), workboxSW.strategies.networkFirst({}), 'GET')

workboxSW.router.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*'), workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({}), 'GET')
```

Why is the font not getting cached?

EDIT #1:
Thanks to Jeff Posnick, I understand what's happening. I haven't figured out the right syntax to pass in the `nuxt.config.js` file, but as an experiment, I hacked the `sw.js` file directly and added these two lines:

```
workboxSW.router.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*'),
    workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}}), 
    'GET')

workboxSW.router.registerRoute(new RegExp('https://fonts.gstatic.com/.*'),
    workboxSW.strategies.cacheFirst({cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}}),
    'GET')
```

That worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For version 2 of workbox and version 2 of @nuxt/pwa, this is the syntax that is needed in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
workbox: {
    runtimeCaching: [
        {
            urlPattern: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*',
            handler: 'cacheFirst',
            method: 'GET',
            strategyOptions: {cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}}
        },
        {
            urlPattern: 'https://fonts.gstatic.com/.*',
            handler: 'cacheFirst',
            method: 'GET',
            strategyOptions: {cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}}
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the fact that Workbox won't cache opaque responses using a `cacheFirst` strategy, unless you specifically tell it to.

This was a common source of confusion with Workbox v2, and we've improved the JavaScript console logs and documentation for the upcoming v3 release. The "[Handle Third Party Requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests)" guide goes into more detail.

You can change your config to

```
runtimeCaching: [{
  urlPattern: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/.*',
  handler: 'cacheFirst',
  method: 'GET',
  cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}
}]
```

to get that behavior in the current v2 release of Workbox.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and example! I'm still struggling with getting the google font cached, though. After adding the cacheableResponse line, the generated sw.js file is not changed from what I posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

tested with `@nuxtjs/pwa@3.0.0-beta.20` and `nuxt@2.11.0`.

`pwa` property below in `nuxt.config.js` created a new cache as expected:

```
  pwa: {
    workbox: {
      runtimeCaching: [
        {
          urlPattern: 'https://my-api-url/.*',
          handler: 'networkFirst',
          method: 'GET',
          strategyOptions: {
            cacheName: 'my-api-cache',
            cacheableResponse: {statuses: [0, 200]}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

could confirm cache content in `Cache Storage` section on Chrome DevTools, Appliation tab.